# IE 8 memory leak while reloading frame in a frameset

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, memory-leaks, frameset

I have included a jquery in a html page which the frame
refers in a frameset and when i refreshed the frame repeatedly, the browser leaks memory.

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <frameset cols="50%,50%*" border="0" frameborder="1" framespacing="1">
        <frame src="link.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" noresize="yes" />
        <frame name="jqueryhost" src="" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" noresize="yes" />
    </frameset>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

link.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="jqueryhost.html" target="jqueryhost">load jQuery in a frame</a>
</body>
</html>
```

jqueryhost.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

</script>

</head>
<body>
    jQuery Host
</body>
</html>
```

Memory Leak Screen Shot

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are not nesting more frames by refreshing the browser?

Comment: There is no question here.... Are you wanting to report a bug with jQuery?  If so you might want to first try using a more recent version... 1.7+

Comment: checked with 1.7.1 jquery version still having the same issue

Comment: IE users deserve this :P. Leave it like that :D

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
    <frameset cols="50%,50%" border="0" frameborder="1" framespacing="1">
        <frame src="link.html" />
        <frame src="jqueryhost.html" />
    </frameset>
</html>
```

and also in your **jqueryhost.html** you have a missing `</script>` closing tag

Answer (score 0):

I would guess (proprietary code makes it impossible to be sure) that the "leak" you see is the previously loaded JQuery scripts. You are in fact able to load a script tag, remove it and then still call global functions that were defined in that tag (I have a sample of this at the end).

So I think what you are seeing is not so much a memory leak, but rather Garbage collection not yet having cleanup up the code that was previously loaded.

Sample of calling functions that have been loaded but removed from the DOM:

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script id="t1" type='text/javascript'>
      function f1(){
        alert("f1");
      }
    </script>
    <script id="t2" type='text/javascript'>
      function f2(){
        alert("f2");
      }
    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      f1();
      f2();
      $("#f1").remove();
      $("#f2").remove();
      f1();
      f2();
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```